# Syntax error in an insert on dbf table

Tags: java, jdbc, foxpro, dbf, visual-foxpro

i am trying to make an insert on a dbf table using jdbc, but every time that i execute the system give me this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.sql.SQLException: [Microsoft][ODBC Visual FoxPro Driver]Syntax error.
at sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbc.createSQLException(Unknown Source)
at sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbc.standardError(Unknown Source)
at sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbc.SQLExecDirect(Unknown Source)
at sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcStatement.execute(Unknown Source)
at sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcStatement.executeQuery(Unknown Source)
at addProduct.test.main(test.java:29)
```

This is the code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws ClassNotFoundException, SQLException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");
    String connString="jdbc:odbc:Driver={Microsoft Visual FoxPro Driver};SourceDB=C:\\RestBar\\DBC;SourceType=DBF";//DeafultDir indicates the location of the db
    Connection connection=DriverManager.getConnection(connString);
    Statement query = connection.createStatement();

    ResultSet result;
    String sql="INSERT INTO CUENTAS (NUM_CTA, NUB_CTA, CAJ_CTA, FEC_CTA, HOR_CTA, " +
            "OPE_CTA, MES_CTA, NOM_CTA, UBI_CTA, PER_CTA, ACU_CTA, USU_CTA, KDI_CTA) " +
            "VALUES('0000001', SELECT DES_MEZ FROM MESAS WHERE COD_MEZ = 'T01', '01', " +
            "'2013/07/18', '16:50:33', 0,'002', SELECT DES_MES FROM MESEROS WHERE COD_MES = '002'," +
            " 'T01', '2',0.00, 01, 0.00)";
    query.execute(sql);


}
```

Comment: use prepared statement, no confusion and much better

Comment: you have a syntax error in your query,  find it and fix it.

Comment: I'm not sure you should be embedding further SELECT statements inside an INSERT statement, also you need to use parameters to circumvent injection attacks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use subqueries, you need to use them as part of a `SELECT`, not as part of the scalar values you list in `VALUES`. And FoxPro does not allow a `SELECT` without a `FROM`.

Your simplified query follows (note that you'll want to remove the line breaks or insert semicolons to wrap the string when you send it to VFP):

```
INSERT INTO CUENTAS (
    NUM_CTA, 
    NUB_CTA, 
    CAJ_CTA, FEC_CTA, HOR_CTA, OPE_CTA, MES_CTA, 
    NOM_CTA, 
    UBI_CTA, PER_CTA, ACU_CTA, USU_CTA, KDI_CTA
) 
SELECT
    '0000001', 
    DES_MEZ , 
    '01', '2013/07/18', '16:50:33', 0,'002', 
    (SELECT DES_MES FROM MESEROS WHERE COD_MES = '002'), 
    'T01', '2',0.00, 01, 0.00
FROM MESAS WHERE COD_MEZ = 'T01'
```

Note that when writing an `INSERT...SELECT` statement, adding proper column names to the SELECT is valid and good practice.

Answer (score 0):

At the very least, when using subqueries you should embed them in an additional set of parenthesis, something like this:

```
VALUES('0000001', (SELECT DES_MEZ FROM MESAS WHERE COD_MEZ = 'T01'), '01', " +
```

I don't know exactly if VFP supports this syntax though, you'll have to verify if the syntax error continues after the change. If not, you can circumvent the limitation by issuing a second query beforehand to get the subquery result, then use that data into the original query as an additional parameter.

Comment: VFP does not support that syntax.